# Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In windows phone i am insert Data to isolated storage in every sec by using

```
System.Threading.Thread startupThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(InsertDB()));
startupThread.Start();

public async Task InsertDB()
{
    //insert to DB
}
```

but if i call InsertDB more than 5 times i am getting Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.
error how to solve this ?

Comment: You're mixing tasks and threads, which is completely incorrect.  You need to go learn how tasks work.

Comment: hi soner, i changed the Task to normal insert but the same issue raised